# yii2-widget-datepicker не подключается

Tags: php, yii2, datepicker, kartik

На платформе `OPENSERVER 5.2` велась разработка на `yii 2 basic`

Понадобилась установить виджет `DatePicker` от `kartik-v`, но без `composer`, т.е. вручную

Вроде был успешно установлен

На локальном ПК (`windows`, `OPENSERVER 5.2`) все нормально работает, но после того как залили сайт на `Linux` выдает ошибку

`Class 'kartik\date\DatePicker' not found`

Содержимое файла вида `view.php`

```
use kartik\date\DatePicker;


$layout = <<< HTML
  <span class="input-group-addon">&nbsp;с&nbsp;</span>
  {input1}
  {separator}
  {input2}
HTML;

echo DatePicker::widget([
  'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_RANGE,
  'model' => $model,
  'attribute' => 'date1',
  'attribute2' => 'date2',                
  'name' => 'from_date',
  'name2' => 'to_date',
  'options' => ['autocomplete' => 'off', 'required' => 'required'],
  'options2' => ['autocomplete' => 'off', 'required' => 'required'],
  'separator' => 'по',
  'form' => $form,
  'layout' => $layout,
  'pluginOptions' => [
    'autoclose'=>true,
    'format' => 'dd.mm.yyyy'
  ]
]);
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что виджет установлен не через composer. Помимо заливки, composer также формирует файл автозагрузки классов согласно инструкции, описанной в `vendor/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker/composer.json`. Т.е. согласно стандарту PSR-4.